# How to find an object model in a one-to-one relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have these two models **user**:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
 attr_accessible :name, :provider, :uid

 # This is a class method, callable from SessionsController 
 # hence the "User." 
 def User.create_with_omniauth( auth)
   user = User.new() 
   user.provider = auth["provider"] 
   user.uid = auth["uid"] 
   user.name = auth["info"]["name"] 
   user.save 
   return user     
  end

 has_one :userprofile
end
```

and **userprofile**:

```
class Userprofile < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :age, :fname, :gender, :lname, :photo_url
end
```

I'd like to check if there's a userprofile object associated to the user. If there's one, display it. Otherwise, create a new one.

I'm trying this and getting an error.

```
def show
 @userprofile = current_user.userprofiles.all.where(:user_id => current_user.uid)
 if !@userprofile.nil? then
   @userprofile
 else
   @userprofile = Userprofile.new
 end
end
```

**undefined method `userprofiles' for #**

I've tried **find** with no better result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

user and userprofile have one-to-one relationship so that

```
@userprofile = current_user.userprofile
```

by using this you can get userprofile of current_user

now your `show` method look like

```
def show
 if current_user.userprofile.present?
   @userprofile = current_user.userprofile
 else
  @userprofile = current_user.build_userprofile
 end
end
```

**Update : why build**

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#has-one-association-reference

we use `build_userprofile` because it's `one-to-one` relation. but suppose if it's has_many relationship then we use `userprofiles_build`

Comment: It is working. I just wonder how am I supposed to guess the existence of the build_userprofile method. Lol! Any link for that?

Comment: better link will be http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs_to-association-reference because there are whole lot of things about associations that we don't know.

Comment: Thank you so much. I come from ASP.NET MVC, most of the concept are exactly the same. But sometimes, there are difference here and there. And In RoR, the "Convetion over configuration" is really extrem, which could be a good thing for experienced developer but a little hard for newbies. Thanks again.

Answer (score 5):

You are calling userprofile in wrong manner. You have to call it like

`@userprofile = current_user.userprofile`

and for the if else block there is a better solution as follows.

```
@userprofile = current_user.userprofile || current_user.userprofile.new
```

this will initialize the user profile if its not created.

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers point out, you don't need the `.all.where(:user_id => current_user.uid)`. The point of making these named associations is that rails can automatically handle looking up all the database id's.

That's also why using the build_userprofile method is a good idea, because it automatically links the new userprofile to current_user. Note that method does not automatically save the newly created record though, so make sure you call save:

```
@userprofile = current_user.build_userprofile
@userprofile.save
```